# SQL Left join on different columns considering specific conditions

Tags: sql, sas, left-join, proc-sql

I believe this is an easy one. Just getting started on SQL, so I am finding it a bit tricky. So I am using SQL on SAS, and I want to join two tables but on different columns based on a value of a column. Practical example:

```
Proc sql;
create table new_table_name as select 
a.proposal_code as new_name_proposal_code,
a.1st_client_code as new_name_1st_client_code,
a.2nd_client_code as new_name_2nd_client_code,
a.3rd_client_code as new_name_3rd_client_code,
a.4th_client_code as new_name_4th_client_code,
a.product_type as new_name_product_type,
b.2nd_client_code
from existing_table a
left join existing table b (on b.2nd_client_code=a.2nd_client_code and a.product_type = "clothes") or 
left join existing table b (on b.2nd_client_code=a.3rd_client_code and (a.product_type = "cars" or a.product_type = "bikes"));
quit;
```

So this is the code that I'm using at the moment, and the goal is to join table a and table b using b.2nd client code = a.2nd client code if the product type from table a is = to "clothes", and if the product type from table a is either "cars" or "bikes", join table a and table b using b.2nd client code = a.3rd client code. Basically, look at two different "on's" regarding the specific product type. When joining these two tables, if one row has product type "clothes", I want it to look at the 2nd client code, if it is either "cars" or "bikes", look at the 3rd client code.

Hope I made it clear. The error I am getting at the moment is "expecting an on". Is it a problem of syntax?

Comment: I dont know about `sas`, but in sql this is invalid: `left join existing table b` . Also the alias `b` should be unique, the second `left join` should have another alias than the first.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to evaluate a complicated expression for the ON criteria.  Unless you want to have the same two records from A and B produce two different outputs when both criteria are satisfied.

Comment: Your variable names are not valid. Names in SAS (and most languages) cannot start with a number.

Comment: You can add a case to your SQL statements, including joins. This would be infinitely simpler if you posted some sample data and expected output.

Comment: And is it possible that both OR conditions can be true at the same time? I suspect they could be....

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  The parentheses before the `on` is not correct.  Your query has other issues as well.  I think you want:

```
create table new_table_name as
    select a.proposal_code as new_name_proposal_code,
           a.1st_client_code as new_name_1st_client_code,
           a.2nd_client_code as new_name_2nd_client_code,
           a.3rd_client_code as new_name_3rd_client_code,
           a.4th_client_code as new_name_4th_client_code,
           a.product_type as new_name_product_type,
           coalsesce(bc.2nd_client_code, bcb.2nd_client_code)
    from existing_table a left join
         existing_table bc
         on bc.2nd_client_code = a.2nd_client_code and
            a.product_type = 'clothes' left join 
         existing_table bcb
         on bcb.2nd_client_code = a.3rd_client_code and
            a.product_type in ('cars', 'bikes');
```

Notes:

- No parentheses *before* the `on` clause.
- No `or left join`.  `or` is a boolean operator.  `left join` is an operator on sets (i.e. tables and results sets).  The don't mix.
- No repeated table aliases.
- You want to combine the two code, so you need something like `coalesce()` in the `select`.
- The SQL delimiter for strings is the single quote, not the double quote.
- `in` is simpler than a string of `or` conditions.

Comment: SAS uses either double or single quotes around strings, even in PROC SQL, unless you explicitly tell it differently via an option in the PROC SQL statement.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, A single quote is missing before the word `bike`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want a complex ON criteria and not two joins.
Something like this:

```
proc sql;
create table new_table_name as 
select 
   a.proposal_code as new_name_proposal_code
  ,a.client_code1 as new_name_client_code1
  ,a.client_code2 as new_name_client_code2
  ,a.client_code3 as new_name_client_code3
  ,a.client_code4 as new_name_client_code4
  ,a.product_type as new_name_product_type
  ,b.client_code2 as new_name_other_client_code2
from tableA a
left join tableB b
  on (b.client_code2=a.client_code2 and a.product_type = "clothes")
  or (b.client_code2=a.client_code3 and a.product_type in ("cars","bikes"))
;
quit;
```

For a better answer post example inputs and desired output.